# mergeMap on a list of Ids fails to build

Tags: angular, http, observable

What is wrong with the syntax here `mergeMap(names => names),`?

```
getIds(): void { 
this.myservice
.getIds.pipe( mergeMap(id => this.getNames(id)), 
mergeMap(names => names), toArray() ) 
}
```

myservce.ts has the following:

```
getIds():Observable<Ids>{
const url = 'http://localhost:4000';
return this.http
    .post(url, '')
    .map(({ Ids }: any) => Ids.map(item => ({Id: item.Id, 
    Name: item.Name }))) as Observable<Ids>;
}

getNames(data: Ids):Observable<any[]> {
  const url ='http://localhost:5000';
  return this.http
    .post(url,data)
    .pipe(map(({ Results }: any) => Results[0].results.map(item => ({Id: item.ID, Name: item.Name }))));
    }
```

The compiler error is (as a newbie I'm not able to figure out):

```
ERROR in src/app/cvetable/mcomponent.ts(132,19): error TS2345:
Argument of type '(names: {}) => {}' is not assignable to parameter 
of type '(value: {}, index: number) => ObservableInput<any[]>'. 
Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<any[]>'. 
Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'Iterable<any[]>'. 
Property '[Symbol.iterator]' is missing in type '{}'.
```

Comment: can u share the editable stackblitz link

Comment: @NinjaJami link is here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hz2ipm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmyservice.ts but doesn't seems to be rigid enough :(

Comment: StackBlitz removes the code that doesnt compile :( Hence posting the code above.

Comment: could you explain in words what you are trying to accomplish? you seems to stick on `mergeMap` but maybe this is not suitable for your need ... or maybe it is but without context its hard to tell

Comment: @anglee are you missing () after this.myservice.getIds ?

Comment: @A.Winnen, that was a typo. I'm trying to simplify the code by posting the relevant portions.

Comment: @ j3ff I'm trying to process the response list Ids from of getIds() in order and run getNames() on each Id.

Answer (score 0):

There's something seriously wrong with the `getIds` method in your Service:

Here's how it should be. Since you're using `HttpClient` and your eg is in Angular 7 which uses Rxjs 6+, you'll have to chain a `.pipe` call to your Observable value in order to apply operators on it. Inside the `.pipe` call, you can then place a list of comma separated operators:

```
getIds(obj):Observable<Ids>{
  return this.http
    .post(this.url, obj)
    .pipe(
      map((Ids: any) => Ids.map(item => ({Id: item.Id, Name: item.Name }) ) )
    )
}
```

Here's an [**Updated StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pdiyeb?file=src/app/myservice.ts) with the errors fixed.

Comment: OK. I've made the change. The compile error is still at the same on the line `mergeMap(names => names),`. Can you please see what I'm missing there?

Comment: I'll need you to share a minimal stackblitz sample replicating your issue. The one you shared previously lacks a lot of things. Please fix it so that it replicates just the issue that you're facing. Please fix other issues on the StackBlitz that are there due to not adding implementation details.

Comment: The StackBlitz runs into other issues. Eg. (no Observable module in rxjs/Rx). I'm still working on creating a simpler example with just this problem.

Comment: The StackBlitz [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hz2ipm) has relevant parts of the code. Please take a look. I'm looking to find a fix for the compile failure that seems like a syntax issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `switchMap` instead of `mergeMap`

```
getIds(): void { 
   this.myservice
   .getIds.pipe(switchMap(id => this.getNames(id))) 
}
```

Comment: OK. But the compile failure is on a diff line. The editable StackBlitz link [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hz2ipm) has the relevant parts of the code.

Comment: Your demo is completely broken. Are expecting others to fix your compilation and syntax issue along with current issue ?

Comment: Sorry; I am only expecting to hear about what is wrong with the syntax in the line that I point out. I cannot post the code because the framework on stackblitz is not the same version as what I have and hence cannot post a working demo with my code.